# How to link oracle table with ax 2009 table?

Tags: ssis, oracle10g, integration, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have to pull data from Oracle's "A-Table" on daily basis and insert the same to Ax "A-Table".

Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the Oracle drivers for Windows ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html ).

Then take a look at this http://floditt.blogspot.mx/2011/08/using-adonet-with-x.html. Instead of using System.Data.SqlClient data types you have to use the oracle classes (System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection, OracleCommand, OracleReader, etc...) which you have installed previously.

If you want it to be run everyday just set a new batch job (in Base -> Inquiries -> Batch job).

Comment: Hi Adria,
Thanks for replying, 
while using system.data.oracleclient.oracle----, it is giving syntax error, I am not able to understand the reason behind. 
Please Help.
Thanks.